# React createBottomTabNavigator with redux store access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to have dynamic tab navigator that is based on data on jwt but i can't figure out how to access redux data from it

this is what i have:

```
const Navigation = ({ jwt }) => {
  console.log('jwt:', jwt);
  return createBottomTabNavigator({
    FeedStack,
    WorkStack,
    ProfileStack,
    RequestStack,
  });
}
const mapStateToProps = ({
  common: { jwt },
}) => ({
  jwt,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navigation);
```

jwt is available but for Navigation is not a valid component so i get this error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Co
mponent instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this functio
```

how can i access props while having valid component to pass to redux?

Comment: can you please explain how you wan't create the dynamic tab navigator.

Comment: Show the code for createBottomTabNavigator. The problem is with what you're returning from the createBottomTabNavigator function

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `createBottomTabNavigation` in a `div` tag.